# Extracting matching groups with Scala regex

Tags: regex, scala

I have a Scala regex that looks like:

```
"fizz<[a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+>"
```

I have a method that uses this regex and compares it to a string argument. If the argument matches the regex, then I want to obtain the first matching group (that is, whatever is the value inside the first `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`), as well as whatever was the second matching group. Thus, if I pass in `"fizz<herp,derp>"` as my argument, I would want to be able to obtain "herp" and "derp":

```
def computeKey(buzz : String) : String = {
    var key : String = "blah"
    val regex = "fizz<[a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+>".r
    if(buzz matches regex) {              // TODO: How do I do this check?
        val firstElement : String = ""    // TODO: Get this (ex: "herp")
        val secondElement : String = ""   // TODO: Get this (ex: "derp")

        // Ex: "herp-derp"
        key = s"${firstElement}-${secondElement}"
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it defining groups in your regexp:

```
val regex = "fizz<([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>".r
```

and then extracting values of the groups this way:

```
buzz match {
  case regex(first, second) => s"$first, $second"
  case _ => "blah"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Nyavro mentioned you need `parenthesis` to extract the matching parts

Apart from the pattern matching you can also do this.

```
val regex = "fizz<([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>".r

val regex(a, b) = "fizz<foo,bar>"
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val regex = "fizz<([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = fizz<([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>


scala> val regex(a, b) = "fizz<foo,bar>"
a: String = foo
b: String = bar
```

This syntax is quite handy but be careful about the case where matching does not happen. when matching does not happen this will throw an exception. So, handle the exception in the code properly.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the accepted answer except some more generic syntax that the OP didn't ask for, and which is almost certainly a bad idea for something like regex matching.